# OutOfRangeStore exception where there is no out of range assignment to an array

Tags: cuda

Capabilities 3.5 (GTX Titan), CUDA 5, VS 2010 and Nsignt. Non-graphical application.

When reaching a certain block size, I am getting `OutOfRangeStore` Exception with description `Memory Space=Global Size=4`.

This works: 10,000 thread with blocksize 4 (and below) or 898 threads with block size 32

This DOESN'T work: 10,000 thread with blocksize 5 (and above) or 899 with block size 32.

When debugging with Nsight, the code is breaking at a place where I am allocating float arrays, such as `float* x = new float[someSmallValue]` and the lines above and bellow are allocating other arrays, so there is no assigning to variables that are out of bound. Actually, the whole function is newing arrays.

If I shuffle the allocation of arrays within the function, I still get the error in the same location, last line of the function.

My hunch is I am reaching a maximum of "something" at the SM level.

**Have you experienced a similar problem before and can you advise me where to look?**

I tried the following:

- Profiling, to see if I am consuming my global memory, however, while I was able to profile transactions and other stuff I wasn't able to profile what is a maximum used global memory of my programme execution, I am using 96 registers, 0 shared memory. I am focusing on "CUDA Launching" section

**Do you recommend looking somewhere else in the profiler?**

- I am looking at the NVCC compiler output when compiling trying to analyse what my program is doing and this is a quote:

```
ptxas : info : Function properties for _Z14DeletePointersP10DevSimTemp
    8 bytes stack frame, 8 bytes spill stores, 8 bytes spill loads ptxas : info : Function properties for fabsf
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads ptxas : info : Function properties for _Z28UpdateTimeStep
    24 bytes stack frame, 20 bytes spill stores, 20 bytes spill loads ptxas : info : Function properties for
_Z21CopyNextStepToRunningP10DevSimTempii
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads ptxas : info : Function properties for
_Z21SendTimeStepToResultsPK19DevSimulationResultP10DevSimTempii
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads ptxas : info : Function properties for
_Z26UpdateCalcsResultsPK19DevSimulationResultP10DevSimTempiiPfPifiiS4_
    64 bytes stack frame, 60 bytes spill stores, 60 bytes spill loads
```

**Could spillage cause a bug? Is that useful from a bug hunting point of view (not from a performance point of view)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are running out of heap space. Only a small chunk of heap space is available by default. You can check how much you have with:

```
size_t heap_size;
cudaDeviceGetLimit(&heap_size, cudaLimitMallocHeapSize);
```

And adjust the value with the corresponding `cudaDeviceSetLimit()` call.

Comment: That was the problem! I have doubled the size of the heap.